# How std::vectors within loop in OpenACC?

Tags: c++, openacc

I have the following code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<double> > > vec { 
        {{1,2},{3,4}, {5,6},{7,8}}, 
        {{9,10}, {11,12}}, 
        {{13,14}, {15,16}, {17,18}} };

    #pragma acc parallel loop
    for (int k = 0; k <3; k++) {

        std::vector<std::vector<double>>& vec2d = vec[k];
        int L = vec2d.size();

        //std::vector<int>dVec{67,51,1,0,50};
        std::vector<double>dVec(L, 0.0);

        for (int i = 0; i < L; i++)
        {
            dVec[i] = vec2d[i][1] - vec2d[i][0];
        }

        for (int j=0; j<2; j++) {
            printf("k: %d j: %d vec0: %f, vec1: %f\n", k, j, vec2d[j][0], vec2d[j][1]);
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"finished\n";

    return 0;
}
```

and I compile with `pgc++ -fast -ta=tesla:cuda9.2,managed -o runEx runEx.cpp -std=c++17 && ./runEx`

if I comment out the `#pragma acc parallel loop`, then it works. But if I leave it there, then I get the error

```
PGCC-S-0155-Procedures called in a compute region must have acc routine information: operator delete (void *) (runEx.cpp: 425)
PGCC-S-0155-Accelerator region ignored; see -Minfo messages  (runEx.cpp: 6)
PGCC/x86-64 Linux 19.10-0: compilation completed with severe errors
```

Also, if I comment out the `std::vector<int>dVec` and the for loop containing it, then the code works even with the `#pragma acc parallel loop`

However, if I change the loop so it becomes just:

```
#pragma acc parallel loop
for (int k = 0; k <3; k++) {
    std::vector<int>dVec{67,51,1,0,50};
}
```

then I get the same error

why is this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that std::vector has some member functions that are not available on the device. The compiler error is specifically calling out `delete`, but I suspected that the `size` function will also be problematic, as well as the constructor. Since you don't control the source of `std::vector`, it's not possible for you to add an `acc routine` to them. The workaround I've done in the past is to strictly use vector outside of OpenACC regions, and pass a raw pointer to its data into the regions. It's a hassle for sure, especially for large codes, but it works. Otherwise, you might also try implementing your own, minimal vector class that does decorate the member functions with `acc routine`. I've seen this done successfully as well.

For a very large L, you might be able to get by putting your `acc parallel loop` solely on your `i` loop, but you'll be copying data back and forth a lot unless you hoist your arrays outside of the `k` loop to enable reuse.

Comment: Then how come the std::vector works for `std::vector<std::vector<double>>& vec2d = vec[k];`? If I keep that in but comment out the `dVec`, then the OpenACC code works fine

Comment: how would I use `dVec` outside the OpenACC region? I need its size to depend on `vec2d`, which I need to be inside the OpenACC region

Comment: "Then how come the std::vector works for std::vector<std::vector<double>>& vec2d = vec[k];" - I think this is because it's a reference to the other vector, which did the actual allocation and such. dVec, on the other hand, is being created and deleted within the loop. You would probably want to allocate it to the max expected size. I got it to run like this, but then you'll need to privatize dVec to get the same behavior and at that point I began getting errors again. I can make it work though if I declare dVec as a plain, static array inside the loop though.

Answer (score -1):

From the site: https://docs.computecanada.ca/wiki/OpenACC_Tutorial_-_Optimizing_loops

I can see too things:

1. Your statement:

```
#pragma acc parallel loop
```

Is missing parameters.

2. The site calls the function with: #pragma acc parallel loop present(row_offsets,cols,Acoefs,xcoefs,ycoefs)
   Which means that the function with 0 parameters is probably illegal.